# PHP: Whats's the difference between the SimpleXMLElement() class and SimpleXML_load_string()?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've seen alot of coders implement `SimpleXML_load_string()` instead of the `SimpleXMLElement()` class. Are there any benefits to using the former over the latter? I've read the [PHP manual on simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). I couldn't manage to get a grasp on what it is.

Any help and guidance (perhaps through examples) would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`simplexml_load_string()` (as the name suggest) load xml from a string and returns an object of `SimepleXMLElement`. There is no difference between this and using just the usual constructor of the class.

Update:

`SimpleXML::__construct()` has an additional parameter (the third one) `bool $data_is_url = false`. If this is `true` the behavior is the same as `simplexml_load_file()` (in conjunction with the common stream wrappers). Thus both `simplexml_load_*()`-functions cover the same functionality as `SimpleXML::__construct()`.

Additional the functions `simplexml_load_*()` has a second parameter `string $class_name = "SimpleXMLElement"` to specify the class of the object to get returned. Thats not a specific feature of the functions, because you can "use" something very similar with usual instanciation too

```
class MyXML extends SimpleXMLElement {}
$a = new MyXML($xml);
$b = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'MyXML');
```

A difference between the OOP- and the procedural approach is, that the functions return `false` on error, but the constructor throws an Exception.

Comment: Not sure how i missed that one. How about remotely retrieving XML using `simplexml_load_string()`? Does it still work the same way as `SimpleXMLElement()`?

Comment: As long as you retrieve the xml data as string, yes (e.g. via `file_get_contents()`). If not, then you a) must set the third argument of `SimpleXMLElement::__construct()`, or b) use `simplexml_load_file()` http://php.net/simplexml-load-file

Answer (score 5):

It's mostly a convenience wrapper. With constructing the base element yourself, you need at least two lines of code to accomplish anything. With [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) a single expression might suffice:

```
 print simplexml_load_string($xml)->title;
```

Is shorter than:

```
 $e = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
 print $e->title;
```

And then of course, there is also the slight variation in the function signature.

> *Update:* And exactly the same length as of
>
> ```
> print(new SimpleXMLElement($xml))->title;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

simplexml_load_string can return a different object:

> class_name
>
> You may use this optional parameter so that
>   simplexml_load_string() will return an
>   object of the specified class. That
>   class should extend the
>   SimpleXMLElement class.

Comment: @VicePrez yep. I can link it if you want, but since you already mention the manual in your question, didn't think it was necessary.