# PHP String to SimpleXML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, string, simplexml

my question is really simple and it's just out of curiosity.

I have a string formatted as XML `<node><child attr="value">data</child><child attr="value">data</child></node>...` and I need to convert it to SimpleXML. I don't have any issue, I know how to do it and how to handle it, I just wanna know what's the difference between

```
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
```

and

```
$xml_data = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

I also would like to know if I am supposed to save the string as a well formatted XML file, with the header `<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>` to avoid any issue. By the way I only need the data to be handled as an array and I will never save it as a file so keep it in mind when you answer

Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just 2 different ways of doing it, the only difference is that the __construct `new SimpleXMLElement` takes an additional argument that allows you to load file from a uri which is the same behavior as using `simplexml_load_file()` instead of _string

About the header it depends on the version of XML you are using,

1.0 is optional, 1.1 is mandatory, have a look at [Does a valid XML file require an xml declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/does-a-valid-xml-file-require-an-xml-declaration)

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer!

Comment: To include the header automatically without having to add it manually as a string, could I just do `$xml_data = $xml_data->asXML();` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this thread which explains the differences between the two different methods:

[PHP: Whats's the difference between the SimpleXMLElement() class and SimpleXML_load_string()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076943/php-whatss-the-difference-between-the-simplexmlelement-class-and-simplexml-l)

I would always include the header unless it is causing you problems just in case

Comment: To include the header automatically without having to add it manually as a string, could I just do `$xml_data = $xml_data->asXML();` ?

Comment: Using the asXML() method will return a string without any of the markup which I'm guessing you do not want.

You could just have a function called createXML() or something similar which you pass the XML to which would prepend the header